# Insert exact number of rows in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to insert *exact* number of rows, for example 100k, into a table, but using *one*, *generic* insert command.

In `Oracle` I use:

```
insert into TABLE 
select dbms_random.value 
  from dual 
connect by level <= 100k;   (or rownum <= 100k)
```

How to do it in SQL Server?

**Edit:**

I want to:

1. have control over HOW MANY records to insert to a table,
2. and do it in one query.

Comment: In sql server you can use TOP. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: For those of us who don't know Oracle that well, can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yeah this seems like an XY question. Possibly should be "How to insert 100,000 random values into a table" instead of "how to insert exact number of rows". There is no concept of `dual` in SQL Server, which is going to throw off the OP for sure.

Comment: I want to have control over how many records i want to insert, with one query. If possible, not using ANY table.

Comment: Then where will the data come from @JakubP? In your question you used the `dual` table

Comment: in Oracle, if You use dual, it comes from nowhere. it's just a dummy replacement.

Comment: BUT it is an actual table, is it not? You can use a sys table in SQL Server or create a numbers / tally table if that's better... @SeanLange has a ton of stuff on tally tables

Comment: @scsimon not my stuff on tally tables. Jeff Moden is the one who first taught me about them and how they can replace loops. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Answer (score 5):

```
INSERT INTO [Table]
SELECT TOP 100000
    [SomeColumn]
FROM [AnotherTable]
```

Comment: Is there a way NOT to select from anything? Just generate some rows. In Oracle selecting `from dual` is just to keep `SELECT ... FROM` syntax.

Comment: Sure @JakubP you could use bulk insert from an excell with 100000 rows, or manually write all of these out. What's the real goal here?

Comment: What type of random values are you looking to generate?

Comment: @JakubP It's not `Dual` it's the `connect by level` with dual that generates the empty rows for you in Oracle.  SQL Server doesn't have a facility like that, so you have to either use a sufficiently large table as a dummy source, or generate spurious empty rows of your own (there's a bunch of different ways to do that).

Comment: Yes, I should have pointed that out, that the point is in "connect by". Thanks @RBarryYoung

Answer (score 3):

It's not as concise as the Oracle syntax, but what about a [recursive CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx)? For instance, here's a query that produces 100,000 GUIDs:

```
declare @count int = 100000;
with cte as
(
    select n = 1, val = newid() -- Base case
    union all
    select n + 1, newid() from cte where n < @count -- Recursive case
)
select val from cte option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Comment: Yikes!!! This will work but using a recursive for counting like this is about the same thing as a cursor. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/ A tally table would be a much better approach to this.

Comment: Good point, @SeanLange. I agree that a tally table is the better approach. But the OP was curious about a solution that didn't require the existence of a source table, so I thought I'd throw it out there.

Comment: This does execute shockingly fast though. I was assuming with 100k guids effectively in a loop it would be slow but not really.

Comment: @SeanLange I have seem some analysis and a loop was not much faster.

Comment: @paparazzo agreed. I was surprised at how fast this actually was. I still tend to avoid using a recursive like this and prefer to use a tally table instead. It is just where my brain goes first.

Comment: It's not bad at 100k rows but, even if it were as fast as a tally table, try running it with STATISTICS IO ON and check the reads...  Yikes!!!! (Bonus upvote to @SeanLange for the use of "yikes")

Comment: @AlanBurstein couldn't agree more. To be honest I thought it would be a noticeable difference with 100k rows from a user standpoint but I didn't notice a perceptible difference in the amount of time for a result to be returned.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way NOT to select from anything? Just generate some
>   rows?...

```
WITH E1(x) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) x(x)),
     E3(x) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b, E1 c)
SELECT TOP (100000) newid() 
FROM E3 a, E3 b;
```